# Set title for Google Maps embed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am embedding a Google Map using their 'Embed this map' code off the Google Maps page.

It works fine, but it always comes up as 'untitled'

```
<div class="google-maps">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!4v1699102345389!6m8!1m7!1sGgTmBPHhKtgAAAQ0MEzJZQ!2m2!1d51.50336287082302!2d-0.1275790069079221!3f336.56!4f-8.700000000000003!5f0.7820865974627469" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
</div>
```

Width and height are defined with CSS

I tried adding a title to the iframe but it didn't do anything.

I also tried using a Google maps API (thinking I might have more flexibility) - the code below, but it doesn't work either. It always says untitled.

```
<iframe
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  title="test"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!4v1699102345389!6m8!1m7!1sGgTmBPHhKtgAAAQ0MEzJZQ!2m2!1d51.50336287082302!2d-0.1275790069079221!3f336.56!4f-8.700000000000003!5f0.7820865974627469?key=my-key-is-here&PARAMETERS"
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I have read through lots of documentation but it's quite confusing.

What I really want it this

https://artsandculture.google.com/streetview/10-downing-street-entrance-hallway-10-downing-street/XAFQY90e99utPA?hl=en-GB&sv_lng=-0.12758047836109654&sv_lat=51.50335969885072&sv_h=-39.31408793346178&sv_p=-6.8567992325994&sv_pid=HMzgivzbj30AAAQ0MExxLg&sv_z=0.33265191522677273

But it doesn't appear that you can embed street views from Google Arts and Culture - only if you navigate there yourself.

I have tried looking at the 'Street View service' in Google developers, but I can't wok out what it is specifically and was hoping there was an easier way as I have lots a street view maps to put on the same page.

I also tried making my own map in 'My Maps' - but the streetview option is not part of it

I'm a bit lost, so really just a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Arts and Culture is a custom website that's not directly related to the Google Maps or its APIs.

You likely obtained the `<iframe>` embed code from google.com/maps:
[image]
Please note that not everything google.com/maps shows is available through the Google Maps Platform APIs.

What is available, though, is embedding [street view](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map#streetview_mode) (and indoor view, if applicable) programmatically via the [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map).

Now, you can specify the camera angle, pitch, etc — but you cannot easily control the "embed title". The `<iframe>` itself may contain the `title` attribute — but that's mostly for [accessibility purposes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#accessibility_concerns).

Your best bet it to place your own HTML on top of the embed:

```css
.google-maps {
  position: relative;
}

.google-maps h2 {
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="google-maps">
  <h2>Embed Title</h2>
  <iframe title="hello world" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!4v1699102345389!6m8!1m7!1sGgTmBPHhKtgAAAQ0MEzJZQ!2m2!1d51.50336287082302!2d-0.1275790069079221!3f336.56!4f-8.700000000000003!5f0.7820865974627469" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here's a [video quickstart](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/quickstart) into the The Maps Embed API.

Comment: Hi Jo - Thanks for your comment. I have managed to get it working using the Google Maps API with

'panorama1.setOptions({ addressControl: false });' 

Which removes the title and then sets my own, but the view it displays isn't consistent. Correct room but wrong view and angle.

I might see if it's more consistent with your approach (not the API)

I take it that there is no issue with putting content over it? As in - I won't get in trouble from Google? Though I guess that's what I a doing at the moment anyway.

And yes, it is from google maps not arts and culture.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - got it. Yea there shouldn't be a problem as long as you don't cover the attribution(s) – Google's logo + any applicable photo sources on the bottom.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for this, I have since realised that the inconsistent view is because it is saving the co-ordinates when I move it. I have since adjusted the code to reset the view on page load. It's all working well - though with 7 maps on the page, and a hope for high traffic, I don't want to get charged. I've set a budget, if I reach it, I will just switch to your option :)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Great to hear! Hope you get the traffic you're after ;) Mind upvoting & accepting the answer if it helped you?

Comment: Hi Joe - yes sure. One more wee question - I don't suppose you know how to get rid of the three numbers (1,2,3) above the rotation icon (but keep the rotation icon)? I can't seem to find anything in 'setOptions' and they look rubbish on mobile, Thanks!

Comment: No, those are not easily hideable. Look into some custom CSS to get rid of them.

Comment: Bummer - I can look at custom CSS, but it usually just overides it

Comment: I got this working by removing the default UI and just adding what I wanted :)

   panorama8.setOptions({ disableDefaultUI: true });
   panorama8.setOptions({ zoomControl: true });
   panorama8.setOptions({ fullscreenControl: true });
   panorama8.setOptions({ panControl: true });